# ROS install from src fails to find rosinstall script

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

It seems like something got deleted from http://packages.ros.org/

The installation from source tutorials are saying to execute the command :

```
wstool init -j8 src http://packages.ros.org/web/rosinstall/generate/raw/groovy/desktop-full
```

However http://packages.ros.org/web no longer exists and thus this command fails.

Is there a backup I can use somewhere?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56579/ros-install-from-src-fails-to-find-rosinstall-script/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.ros.org/question/56515/groovy-generator-error/

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-02-28**:
Thanks, apparently I didn't see that one.